# Failed Plone 4.1.4 install: lxml build failed: libxml2:

Tags: plone

### Expected Outcome:

```
Successful installtion of Plone 4.1.4
```

### Actual Outcome:

```
Installation fails with: libxml2: cmmi failed:
```

### Stack:

```
Ubuntu  Ubuntu 10.04.4 LT (Lucid)
Apache 2.2.14
Plone-4.1.4-UnifiedInstaller
```

### Install System Libraries, Header Files, etc

> ```
> root@li54-28:~#apt-get update
> root@li54-28:~#apt-get install g++ python-dev python-setuptools python-lxml python-libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev openssl subversion
> ```

### Install Plone

```
joeblow@li54-28:~/Plone-4.1.4-UnifiedInstaller$ ./install.sh standalone --target=${HOME} --instance=joeblow.org
```

> `Stand-Alone Zope Instance selected`
>
> ```
> Detailed installation log being written to /home/joeblow/Plone-4.1.4-UnifiedInstaller/install.log
>
> Rootless install method chosen. Will install for use by system user joeblow
>
> Installing Plone 4.1.4 at /home/joeblow
>
> Skipping libjpeg build
> Skipping zlib build
> Skipping readline build
> Installing Python 2.6.7. This takes a while...
> Patching for thread size
> Installing distribute...
> Python build looks OK.
> Unpacking buildout cache to /home/joeblow/buildout-cache
> Compiling .py files in egg cache
> Copying Plone-docs
> Generating random password ...
> ****Your platform's xml2/xslt are missing or out-of-date. We'll need to build them.****
> Copying buildout skeleton
> Fixing up bin/buildout
> Building lxml with static libxml2/libxslt; this takes a while...
>
> lxml build failed. You may wish to clean up and try again
> without the lxml build by adding --without-lxml to the
> command line.
> Buildout returned an error code: 1; Aborting.
> Buildout failed. Unable to continue
>
> Installation has failed.
> See the detailed installation log at /home/joeblow/Plone-4.1.4-UnifiedInstaller/install.log
> to determine the cause.
> ```
>
> ***Notice the installer says: **Your platform's xml2/xslt are missing or out-of-date** and then trys to build them. But I already installed them via apt-get install...

### Troubleshooting

```
joeblow@li54-28:~/Plone-4.1.4-UnifiedInstaller$ tail -75 install.log
```

/

```
bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls   -o testReader testReader.o ./libxml2.la  -lz  -lm
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -o .libs/testReader testReader.o  ./.libs/libxml2.so -ldl -lz -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/joeblow/joeblow.org/parts/lxml/libxml2/lib
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./include  -D_REENTRANT      -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -MT testapi.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/testapi.Tpo -c -o testapi.o testapi.c
testapi.c: In function âtest_xmlBufferSetAllocationSchemeâ:
testapi.c:18773: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
testapi.c: At top level:
testapi.c:17989: warning: âgen_xmlSchematronPtrâ defined but not used
testapi.c:17992: warning: âdes_xmlSchematronPtrâ defined but not used
testapi.c:18009: warning: âgen_xmlSchematronParserCtxtPtrâ defined but not used
testapi.c:18012: warning: âdes_xmlSchematronParserCtxtPtrâ defined but not used
testapi.c:34157: warning: âgen_xmlSAXHandlerPtr_ptrâ defined but not used
testapi.c:34160: warning: âdes_xmlSAXHandlerPtr_ptrâ defined but not used
gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [testapi.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/tmp8quJWJbuildout-libxml2/libxml2-2.7.8'
**make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/tmp8quJWJbuildout-libxml2/libxml2-2.7.8'
make: *** [all] Error 2
**libxml2: cmmi failed:** /tmp/tmp8quJWJbuildout-libxml2**
While:
  Installing lxml.

An internal error occured due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joeblow/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1683, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/home/joeblow/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 555, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/home/joeblow/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1227, in _call
    return f()
  File "/home/joeblow/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.recipe.staticlxml-0.7.2-py2.6.egg/z3c/recipe/staticlxml/__init__.py", line 169, in install
    self.build_libxml2()
  File "/home/joeblow/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.recipe.staticlxml-0.7.2-py2.6.egg/z3c/recipe/staticlxml/__init__.py", line 129, in build_libxml2
    loc = self.xml2_cmmi.install()
  File "/home/joeblow/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.recipe.cmmi-1.3.4-py2.6.egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 99, in install
    self.build()
  File "/home/joeblow/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.recipe.cmmi-1.3.4-py2.6.egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 182, in build
    self.cmmi(dest)
  File "/home/joeblow/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.recipe.cmmi-1.3.4-py2.6.egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 208, in cmmi
    system("make")
  File "/home/joeblow/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.recipe.cmmi-1.3.4-py2.6.egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 31, in system
    raise SystemError("Failed", c)
SystemError: ('Failed', 'make')
```

******** *PICKED VERSIONS* ***********
[versions]

******** */PICKED VERSIONS* **********

### libxml2-dev Package Info

```
root@li54-28:~# apt-cache show libxml2-dev
```

> ```
> Package: libxml2-dev
> Priority: optional
> Section: libdevel
> Installed-Size: 2116
> Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
> Original-Maintainer: Debian XML/SGML Group <debian-xml-sgml-pkgs@lists.alioth.debian.org>
> Architecture: i386
> Source: libxml2
> Version: 2.7.6.dfsg-1ubuntu1.4
> Replaces: libxml2 (<= 2.6.6-1), libxml2-headers (= 2.6.7-1)
> Depends: libxml2 (= 2.7.6.dfsg-1ubuntu1.4), zlib1g-dev | libz-dev
> Conflicts: libxml2 (<= 2.6.6-1), libxml2-headers (= 2.6.7-1)
> Filename: pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2-dev_2.7.6.dfsg-1ubuntu1.4_i386.deb
> Size: 753312
> MD5sum: 5c7bc3d0979cf1078ebee42b199d454a
> SHA1: 9bc9c14507b08c0a9e192fa4d136c84af1e4079b
> SHA256: 426c56e2ef30f3c1341126f736f084b73b506c17bb339f92e1b2c18745e6eed9
> Description: Development files for the GNOME XML library
>  XML is a metalanguage to let you design your own markup language.
>  A regular markup language defines a way to describe information in
>  a certain class of documents (eg HTML). XML lets you define your
>  own customized markup languages for many classes of document. It
>  can do this because it's written in SGML, the international standard
>  metalanguage for markup languages.
>  .
>  Install this package if you wish to develop your own programs using
>  the GNOME XML library.
> Homepage: http://xmlsoft.org/
> Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
> Origin: Ubuntu
> Supported: 18m
>
> Package: libxml2-dev
> Priority: optional
> Section: libdevel
> Installed-Size: 2116
> Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
> Original-Maintainer: Debian XML/SGML Group <debian-xml-sgml-pkgs@lists.alioth.debian.org>
> Architecture: i386
> Source: libxml2
> Version: 2.7.6.dfsg-1ubuntu1
> Replaces: libxml2 (<= 2.6.6-1), libxml2-headers (= 2.6.7-1)
> Depends: libxml2 (= 2.7.6.dfsg-1ubuntu1), zlib1g-dev | libz-dev
> Conflicts: libxml2 (<= 2.6.6-1), libxml2-headers (= 2.6.7-1)
> Filename: pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2-dev_2.7.6.dfsg-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
> Size: 750710
> MD5sum: 7272dcc6226fa95ab767f382aa562862
> SHA1: b049bffa4a86c1ade69d0f2e6cf1ee88a675149e
> SHA256: b9df88fafe1ed33bd029127d216cffce98ada1201b22802657ef5be1f77e016c
> Description: Development files for the GNOME XML library
>  XML is a metalanguage to let you design your own markup language.
>  A regular markup language defines a way to describe information in
>  a certain class of documents (eg HTML). XML lets you define your
>  own customized markup languages for many classes of document. It
>  can do this because it's written in SGML, the international standard
>  metalanguage for markup languages.
>  .
>  Install this package if you wish to develop your own programs using
>  the GNOME XML library.
> Homepage: http://xmlsoft.org/
> Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
> Origin: Ubuntu
> Supported: 18m
> ```

### NOTES

Even though the Plone install failed, it still created the website directory, a buildout.cfg, and a curious looking file named **lxml_static.cfg**

I couldn´t find much about lxml_static.cfg but i did encounter this [link](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.recipe.staticlxml#id12). Since the install failed completely and this looks like an entirely different buldout I am unsure if it is directly related.

Any hints?

Comment: This class of problem is probably better handled by a bug report than a stackoverflow query.
Also, we'll need an actual Ubuntu version. If it's a testing/unstable release (which is what squeeze/sid may indicate), you're probably on your own.

Comment: root@li54-28:/home# cat /etc/debian_version
squeeze/sid

root@li54-28:/home# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS"

root@li54-28:/home# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid

Comment: Sorry that is so messy. I just learned /etc/lsb-release is far more accurate than /etc/debian_version. Updating the STACK section to reflect more accurate info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This class of problem is probably better handled by filing a ticket at dev.plone.org.

Your system has libxml2, but the libxslt is probably not adequate; this is true of all but the most current releases.

The install.log report unfortunately isn't very helpful. The pertinent line is:

```
gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
```

but that gives no indication of why it was killed. However, this does tell us that gcc was killed by an outside process rather than by something like a compilation error. Your system logs may tell you something more (e.g., killed process XXX for reason YYY).

Is it possible that your user limits are set so conservatively that they won't allow a memory/cpu intensive build? If so, check with your sysadmin.

Comment: I reviewed /var/log/messages for evidence of "cc1":

Comment: root@li54-28:/var/log# grep cc1 messages
Mar 21 14:37:40 li54-28 kernel: cc1 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
Mar 21 14:37:40 li54-28 kernel: Pid: 22925, comm: cc1 Not tainted 2.6.39.1-linode34 #1
Mar 21 14:37:40 li54-28 kernel: [22925]  1037 22925    12128     9131   1       0             0 cc1

Comment: A little search engine grease revealed: oom-killer is a kernel function that shoots down [large|random]
processes when you start running out of memory.

Comment: shadqudsi@li54-28:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 20
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbtes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

Comment: Thanks for your help SteveM. I will try adjusting these values. If that doesn´t work i will file a bugreport with dev.plone.org

Comment: Changed my ulimit settings and rebuilt plone... same error condition.

Comment: So basically i can´t install plone on my server?

Comment: The install failed but it created the joeblow.org directory. Using the buildout.cfg located in the joeblow.org directory.... I tried statically compiling lxml by incorporating the lxml, pyxml and other elements into my buildout as seen here: Per http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.recipe.staticlxml...

Comment: But it falied with: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/joeblow/joeblow.org/./setup.py

Comment: Im running out of lithium crystal captain :)

Comment: So i gave up on installing plone 4.1.4 with lxml :(   So installed with out lxml:`code` ./install.sh standalone --target="${HOME}/plone" --instance=${WEBSITE_NAME} --without-lxml`code`

Answer (score 2):

As an FYI we use the following for Ubuntu before we deploy Plone from unified installer:

```
apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libbz2-dev libssl-dev p7zip-full rar lha unrar unzip unace unp bzip2 gzip patch
```

Comment: Thanks @Senner. Updated my apt-get install line.

Comment: Sweet. Totally fixed me. I had libxml2 and libxslt current but some of that other stuff was out of date (on Mint 14) so your update fixed the problem. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I hit a potential bug (Thanks @SteveM) trying to install Plone 4.1.4 on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LT (Lucid). If you are having a similar issue you can track the potential bug here: [dev.plone.org/ticket/12795](http://dev.plone.org/ticket/12795)

**Work Around Solution: Install without lxml!!**

```
./install.sh standalone --target="${HOME}/plone" --instance=${WEBSITE_NAME} --without-lxml
```

Thanks for Playing