# Permission denied - Static Lxml Build Failed - Plone - CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, plone

I am using the Unified Installer for Plone 5.0 on CentOS server.

`./install.sh zeo --target="${HOME}/plone" --static-lxml --build-python`

CentOS has an older version of lxml2 library so I have to build static lxml & Python. Error is as follows:

```
lxml: Static build requested.
Installing lxml.
lxml: CMMI libxml2 ...
lxml: Using libxml2 download url ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz
libxml2: Downloading ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz
libxml2: Unpacking and configuring
sh: ./configure: Permission denied
libxml2: cmmi failed: /tmp/tmpAyLWxdbuildout-libxml2
While:
  Installing lxml.
```

Error says "Permission denied", so I tried installing with sudo and logging in as root. Also changed permissions of /tmp to 777. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Just a wild guess - try running `bin/buildout -c lxml_static.cfg` when logged in as root.  I guess that running the full buildout won't work because of the `buildout-user` option in buildout.cfg

Comment: Or use --without-xml as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815659/failed-plone-4-1-4-install-lxml-build-failed-libxml2?rq=1)

Comment: What's your CentOS version?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reach read/write permission for root user. You can simply change your user to root.

```
$ su -
```

Or if your user is in sudoers group you can use;

```
$ sudo ./install.sh ....
```

You can check if your user is in sudoers group or not with

```
root$ cat /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The installer was running a script in /tmp which was set to non-executable. Remount /tmp as executable and it works fine.

Comment: You may also use a command line like:

    TMPDIR=/home/mylogin/temp ./install.sh zeo --static-lxml

Probably a bit easier than remounding /tmp ;)

Comment: I had tried setting TMPDIR to my home dir, but for some reason that didn't work. I think it's because the install script downloads an archive from the web and extracts it into /tmp instead of my TMPDIR. Thanks for the response